# java code to get the count details from log

Tags: java, logging

Need to write code to parse the log file which contains below ReportGen details and  need implement the below details in the code .tried little bit new to java.

total count of ReportGen requests with size <100kB,
        total count of all non ReportGen requests,
        total response time of ReportGen requests with size >=100kB,
        total response time of ReportGen requests with size <100kB,
        total response time of all non ReportGen requests

```
Any pseudo code please:

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

public class TestAutomation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            int count =0;

            String pattern="http://ontology.buffalo.edu";

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                 if (sCurrentLine.contains("PDFGen")){
                        count++;

                        System.out.println(count + ".query: " );
                        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                    } 

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your question/problem exactly?

Comment: need to write code for the below condition total count of ReportGen requests with size <100kB
    total count of all non ReportGen requests
    total response time of ReportGen requests with size >=100kB
    total response time of ReportGen requests with size <100kB
    total response time of all non ReportGen requests
    total size of ReportGen requests with size >=100kB
    total size of ReportGen requests with size <100kB
    total size of all non ReportGen requests

Comment: and what's ReportGen?

Comment: reportGen is like PDF Generated